# Ipython notebook extensions not showing full menu

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I tried to get the extension working and installed it via,

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_nbextensions_configurator
```

I get an extension symbol but not the menu with the options. See below:

[image: Extension missing menu]

Comment: You mean there is no option to enable it?

Comment: I should see many options below it , in the picture, they are just not there :(

Comment: I guess you should ask jupyter_nbextensions_configurator on github